# Ionic Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am creating ionic 3 app with WordPress backend. Here is my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from "ionic-angular";
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';


import { WordpressProvider } from './../../providers/wordpress/wordpress'; 
import { PostPage } from './../../pages/post/post';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-blog',
  templateUrl: 'blog.html',
})
export class BlogPage {

  posts: any = [];
  private loading: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public wordpress: WordpressProvider,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,  
    public viewCtrl: ViewController,
  ) { 
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
    this.loading.present();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad BlogPage'); 
    this.wordpress.retrievePosts().subscribe(results => {
      this.posts = results;
      this.loading.dismiss();  
    });
  } 

  openPostPage(post) {
    this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, {"post": post});
  }

}
```

Now i call in header

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="white_bg">  
      <ion-buttons left>
        <button ion-button (click)="viewCtrl.dismiss()">
          <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title center toolbar-title><img src="./assets/images/logo.png" class="logo"/></ion-title>   
      <ion-buttons end>
          <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
          </button> 
      </ion-buttons> 
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
```

this give me this error

**Runtime Error**
Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root page

Can anyone point what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How about your app.html? which is the main view of you app. There should something like:

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

It define your root view, which is `rootPage`, and in your `main.ts` you set your rootPage.

Comment: yes, like this <ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>

Comment: found issue, when i click on menu item, it was calling this.nav.setRoot(), i change this to this.nav.push() and issue resolved. Thanks anyways